# How to chain operations with side effects?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have two methods that allows to get an access to underlying storage in async manner

```
private Mono<String> read(String key) { }
private Mono<Boolean> delete(String key) { }
```

I want to create another async method that will read value and delete it immediately with returning of read value. I was able to manage it in a really ugly way.

```
public Mono<String> readAndDelete(String key) {
    Mono<String> read = read(key).cache();
    return read.then(delete(key)).then(read);
}
```

But I'm sure more elegant and correct way to do it have to exist. How I can achieve it?

Beside answer proposed by Auktis, similar effect can be achieved with `delayUntil` method

```
public Mono<String> readAndDelete(String key) {
    return read(key).delayUntil(value -> delete(key));
}
```

In accordance to documentation `delayUnit` resolves mono, then triggers another mono specified as an argument and finally returns the result of the first resolved mono.

Comment: Are you looking for `doOnSuccess`?

Comment: `doOnSuccess` accepts `Consumer`, so it is possible to react to read, but it doesn't allow to schedule `delete` method call. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "schedule"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition of a − I hope − more elegant way:

```java
public Mono<String> readAndDelete(String key) {
    return read(key)
        .flatMap(value -> delete(key)
            .thenReturn(value)
        );
}
```